# Zend_Db join query

Tags: database, zend-framework

I am trying to apply join query on 3 tables in Zend_Db.My query is as follow:

```
$id_array = array("1","2");

$query = $this->select();
$query->from(array('b' => 'brands'), array('b.brand_id','b.brand_name'))->where('b.brand_id NOT in (?)', $id_array)->order('RAND()')->limit(5);
$query->join(array('p' => 'product'), 'b.brand_id = p.brand_id', array('p.product_id', 'p.product_price'));
$query->join(array('pimg' => 'product_img_map'), 'p.product_id = pimg.product_id', array('pimg.img_location'));
$query->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$resultRows = $this->fetchAll($query);
return $resultRows;
```

In that one brand may have more than one product,but in query I am applying limit to brand table i.e 5. By default it is applied to product also because if one brand having 5 products it is only giving information of one brand.Is there any suggestion on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a sub-query to obtain the desired results:

```
$id_array = array("1","2");

$subQuery = $this->select()
    ->from(array('b' => 'brands'), array('b.brand_id','b.brand_name'))
    ->where('b.brand_id NOT in (?)', $id_array)
    ->order('RAND()')
    ->limit(5);
$query = $this->select()
    ->from(array('b' => $subQuery), array('*'))
    ->join(array('p' => 'product'), 'b.brand_id = p.brand_id', array('p.product_id', 'p.product_price'))
    ->join(array('pimg' => 'product_img_map'), 'p.product_id = pimg.product_id', array('pimg.img_location'));
```